# Why is my question being closed?

Tags: discussion

My [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242269/is-hoover-capitalised) has one close vote already. Being relatively new to the site (and witnessing some high-rep users treat lower-rep users without the amount of respect they deserve) I am unsure as to why it has received such a vote.

The question was suggested to be a duplicate of two other questions (I did check for similar previous questions before asking), but I don't see how the names of cheeses are relevant to brand names.

Comment: The question is almost identical to this one asked way back in 2011 (an eternity Internetwise) [Should capitals be used when verbing trademarks?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15458/should-capitals-be-used-when-verbing-trademarks.) I hope you agree that the answers in that post were helpful, if however, they have NOT satisfied you. You can edit your post explaining *why* you want to reopen your question.

Comment: P.S I have no idea as to what the tag "antimeria" means on that post. I still have to get round to doing that. UPDATE: *In rhetoric*, **anthimeria**, *traditionally and more properly called **antimeria**, is the substitution of one part of speech for another, most commonly the use of a noun as if it were a verb.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with disrespect, and everything (and really only) to do with the question being pretty much a duplicate. Votes here are on questions and answers, not people.

No one I know of actually likes down votes or close votes, but that is a huge part of how this site works. It's not meant to be hurtful at all. Cheeses? Did you read @Edwin Ashworth's answer? He even mentions *hoover*.

We've had many more than 50,000 questions here. Some are exact duplicates, even when they are worded differently. It's bound to happen.

Comment: Thank you @medica. I did read his comment and it did help with my question, though I didn't see anything on the capitalisation of a noun. I'm actually surprised you're not a moderator; you'd be a good one!

Comment: @WindowsDude7 - My first question here was closed as a duplicate. No one is immune! ') I'm glad I could help. (Our mods are incredibly good, btw.)

Comment: For new visitors to the site, @WindowsDude7 recently changed his moniker to Dog Lover.